# Como setar flash na view do CAKEPHP?

Tags: cakephp

No método no meu controller eu seto a flash, de acordo com a condição.

```
if ($this->Auth->user()) {  
//redireciona apos o login;  

echo $this->Session->setFlash("Bem-vindo");  
}
```

Como posso exibir isso diretamente da view, ao invés de exibir no método? Por exemplo, o método retornaria `true` em caso de logado e na página para a qual redirecionei o usuário eu acessaria a mensagem do flash ou algo do tipo.

Não quero usar `echo`, já que é uma mensagem curta e temporária ou até que a página seja recarregada ou atualizada.

Já tentei acessar o `$this->Session->setFlash()`, mas dá erro de helper. Talvez, eu criando um helper resolveria o problema então?  O $`this->Session->flash()` não tem mensagem. Só acessaria um componente, no caso poderia ser o `Auth`, por exemplo: `$this->Session->flash('Auth');`

Alguém sugere algo?

Answer (score 2):

Não sei qual versão do CakePHP você está usando, mas na 1.2 basta usar o helper $session e chamar o método flash() sem o "echo"

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
if ($session -> check('Message.flash')) {
  $session -> flash();
}
?>
<div>sua pagina normal</div>
</body>
```

Link: http://api.cakephp.org/1.2/class-SessionHelper.html#_flash

Answer (score 0):

Como você não especificou em qual versão, estou complementando a resposta do **Claytinho**

Na versão [2.x do CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html)

```
// In the view.
echo $this->Session->flash();
```

Na versão [3.x do CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/flash.html)

```
// In your Controller
$this->Flash->success('The user has been saved', [
    'key' => 'positive',
    'params' => [
        'name' => $user->name,
        'email' => $user->email
    ]
]);

// In your View
<?= $this->Flash->render('positive') ?>

<!-- In src/Template/Element/Flash/success.ctp -->
<div id="flash-<?= h($key) ?>" class="message-info success">
    <?= h($message) ?>: <?= h($params['name']) ?>, <?= h($params['email']) ?>.
</div>
```